# Excel Conditional Formatting Not Working Properly (yes, I'm using decimals)

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

Does anyone happen to know why my conditional formatting icon set is not working properly?

I've scoured the internet, and everything I find is in reference to the fact that people are using whole numbers instead of decimals.

I'm using decimals, and Excel is refusing to do my bidding.

Conditional Formatting Error

[image: 1]

Comment: could it be that you have to change the type to "number" instead of "percent" to achieve what you want?

Comment: I've fiddled with all of those settings, and nothing is working :(

Comment: I tried it. When I use Percent I got it wrong, but different from your result. If I chose Number it got right.
I *typed* the numbers. In your Progress column, they might be calculated. Maybe the calculation makes the differens.